# maven use a different directory for site source files than src/site

Tags: configuration, maven-2, build

I need to configure where my Maven 2 project's site files are located, by default they are src/site/, I'd like to point them to src-documentation/site, how would I override Maven's default conventin?

Answer (score 2):

As [maven-site-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/site-mojo.html#siteDirectory) documentation says you need to configure plugin

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <siteDirectory>${basedir}/src-documentation/site</siteDirectory>          
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```